# iOS 14: App freezes without crash report on updating constraint constant

Tags: swift, xcode, crash, nslayoutconstraint, ios14

I have a strange issue on updating a `NSLayoutConstraint` constant value.

I have a view controller with a custom UIView (which acts as a bottom sheet / card).
Inside my `UIView` class I am updating the views height constraint based on the attached `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. This works perfectly. As soon as the gesture ends, I am animating the height constraint to a particular value. At this POINT, the app completely freezes without a crash report. What's even strange is that it freezes on particular devices only: eg iPhone Pro 11 Max / Pro, iPhone X. It is working seamlessly on an iPhone SE or iPad.

The app becomes unresponsive and the memory continually increases and rapidly.

Anybody has ANY clue what's going on?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this?

Comment: Yes, my UIView used a UIScrollView inside. The following line fixed the crash: 
scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always

Comment: Be sure to also call super.viewWillLayoutSubviews() (UIViewController class) and super.layoutSubviews() (UIView class) in case you are overriding these methods. I had a similar case where the app was crashing where I had to call these.

Comment: contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior saved the day! xD

Comment: Wuhoo! Adding it is an answer.

Comment: Yeah! in my case, it was increasing the memory footprint of the app indefinitely, until killed by the OS. Its very weird because completely unrelated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After hours of debugging. Hope this helps someone:

My UIView used a UIScrollView inside. The following line fixed the crash:

`scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always`